# C Return Going Back To Loop Predicate Not Ending The Function

Tags: c, loops, return

Hello I have the following code in C and when the code clause:

```
if (idx - 1 == 0) {
    return opening_address;
}
```

executes it returns to the While loop's predicate rather than actually returning and ending the function. The code does get hit and likewise for the other return statement in the loop and both have the same behavior and basically do a continue action.

```
int find_smallest_free_block(int block_size) {

    int opening_address = 0;
    int idx = 0;

    while (idx + lowestPower <= highestPower) {
        if (powers[idx].hasHoles) {
            
            if (powers[idx].size > block_size) {
                opening_address = powers[idx].head_p->start_address;

                // Add 2 holes to the next power down
                int try = 0;
                try = addHole(idx - 1, powers[idx].head_p->start_address, powers[idx].head_p->end_address / 2);
                try = addHole(idx - 1, powers[idx].head_p->end_address / 2, powers[idx].head_p->end_address);
                
                // Remove hole at power
                try = removeHole(idx, powers[idx].head_p->start_address);
            
                if (idx - 1 == 0) {
                    return opening_address; // cant make holes at lowest level
                }
                idx -= 1;
                continue;
            } else { 
                return opening_address;
            }
        }
        idx += 1;
    }

    return opening_address;
}
```

Comment: "it returns to the While loop's predicate rather than actually returning and ending the function." - what does that even mean?

Comment: This is not C++ code.  Do not tag C++ if the code is C.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, when the return statement is executed the control flow is routed to the predicate in the while loop; the return statement should jump back to the calling function not remain in the loop let alone the function.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. The chance your program does not return from the function when a `return` statement is essentially zero; it can happen only if your machine malfunctions or there is undefined behavior in your program, and even then the probability is near zero. Almost certainly you have misinterpreted the symptoms, and hence you should provide a [mre] that can be examined.

Comment: Please tell us what you do and observe, rather than what you conclude from your observations. For example "I run the program in the debugger, I type A, B, and C, and the debugger shows X, Y, and Z".